# JSF - Filtering datatable : could not resolve property: globalFilter

Tags: jsf, primefaces, filter, datatable

I want to implement global filtering on datatable :

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="myVars" value="#{myBean.vars}" widgetVar="varsTable"   
        emptyMessage="Empty" filteredValue="#{myBean.filteredVars}">  

     <f:facet name="header">  
        <p:outputPanel>  
            <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />  
            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="varsTable.filter()" style="width:150px" />  
        </p:outputPanel>  
    </f:facet>  

    <p:column filterBy="#{myBean.id}" 
    filterMatchMode="contains"
    filterStyleClass="filter_hide">  
        <h:outputText value="#{myBean.id}" />  
    </p:column>
```

myBean :

```
 private List<Vars> filteredVars;

 // getter & setter
```

But when I write any letter in the inputText, I get this error :

```
 could not resolve property: globalFilter of: Vars
```

Do you know why I get this error ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `private List<Var> filteredVars;` ?

Comment: My bad, if forgot some 's' ! Edited.

Comment: Can you provide the whole content of your bean (you do have another List named "var" don't you?) . Here there is everything you need to create such a filter: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf